# Can we keep 2 or more org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID in eclipse plugin_customization.ini file

Tags: java, eclipse, key-bindings

I have added key binding for "F7" key and we have an existing binding scheme id "abc.scheme" which is used for sequence "M1+D" added in plugin_customization.ini

```
'''org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=abc.scheme'''
```

But I want an new scheme id to be bind for the F7 key, so created "xyz.scheme" id and added in  plugin_customization.ini like

```
'''org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=abc.scheme,xyz.scheme'''
```

But it dose not work for this,

Is it possible to add 2 or more KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID in plugin_customization.ini , If Yes then How?

Comment: That key sets the active scheme, there can only be one active scheme.

Comment: @greg-449 scheme id "abc.scheme" is used it for M1+D sequence, same schem id I don't want to use it for F7, so I have created "xyz.scheme" id and this id i need to be use it for "F7" sequence, then how can i add  "abc.scheme" and "xyz.scheme" in my plugin_customization.ini , so that the seperate scheme should work for sequence "M1+D" and "F7"

Comment: You don't add schemes in the plugin_customization.ini. You define schemes using the `scheme` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point.  `org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID` just sets which scheme is the active one. You **cannot** have more than one scheme active at a time. Possibly what you want is a Context defined using `org.eclipse.ui.contexts` extension point - you can have many of these and activate and deactivate them.